# Problemas Con Xcode... storyboard & ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

seguido me está sucediendo que el storyBoard no conecta con la clase ViewController al iniciar proyecto,  esto esta sucediendo mas y mas seguido, ya he borrado el archivo y creado uno nuevo con la clase como es debido... pero! otra cosa sucede... las librerías no las reconoce, como UserNotifications, AVfoundation etc etc... no es la primera vez, y en otros Mac también me llegó hacer lo mismo, alguien le ha pasado?? la solución pues es cerrar y crearlo nuevamente... es un poco molesto y después llega a fastidiar.

ya he seleccionado en modo manual el archivo pero eso NO funciona, y ahora esta en automático como pueden ver en la siguiente foto como ejemplo: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: descubrí un bug en Xcode, se queda indexando de manera permanente al crear el proyecto, se puede guardar y después abrir o borrarlo y crear otro, y si tienen un proyecto ya creado solo reiniciar Xcode y con eso queda solucionado, es un bug que tiene Xcode me paso tambien con Xcode 7, 8 y 9, los de apple me dijeron que cuando se queda indexando al parecer se crea un bucle infinito al querer indexar con el storybard, pero solo tendría que reiniciar el proyecto y listo... pero esperar a que indexe el proyecto.

Answer (score 1):

Que versión de Xcode tienes? Intenta usar una antes de la actual, ya ves que con cada release luego se generan problemas, y procura utilizar Clean también cada vez que quieras compilar el proyecto

Comment: utilizo Xcode 8.3.3, lo curioso es cuando creo los proyectos, cuando trabajo regularmente puedo compilar sin problemas, el detalle es cuando se crean, me había pasado un par de veces con Xcode 7 en sus ultimas versiones, aun así muchas gracias!